# Finding basis from span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I just need someone to check if I'm doing this properly.

---

Find a basis for: $span\{(1,1,1),(1,0,1),(0,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$

---

I formed matrix A using these 4 vectors as columns;

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&0&0&1\\1&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}^T$

$rref = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-1\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}^T$

I'm a bit uncertain about the next step. I have pivots in the first two columns, meaning they are linearly independent, so does that mean my basis is just the first two columns of $A$?

$basis=\{ (1,1,1), (1,0,1) \}$

Comment: I think you should operate row reduction on the *transposed* matrix to see that – or operate column-reduction.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand... I should write the vectors as rows rather than as columns? If so - how do I get a set of linearly independent vectors from this?

Comment: It's to interpret the results more easily: when you have a linear combination of rows, it exactly corresponds to a linear combination of the vectors. This is not the case without transposing.

Comment: So the math is right, but I haven't written it very well? Or the math is wrong and I've written it nonsensically?

Comment: Row reduction as you wrote it leads to determining the *linear relations* between the vectors. Here you obtain the relation $v_1-v_2+v_4=0$. So, as  we're in dimension $3$, you know the system of vectors has rank $2$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm so bad at this that I'm having trouble following how this ties back to transposing/column-reduction. Is it better with my (minor) edits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53030/discussion-between-bernard-and-kookiemonster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The span is all linear combinations of the basis vectors.

$(1,1,1) = (1,0,1) + (0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0) = 0*(1,0,1)$ so we can remove these two vectors from a potential basis.

$\alpha(1,0,1) + \beta(0,1,0) = (\alpha,\beta,\alpha) = (0,0,0)$ only when $\alpha = \beta = 0$.

Thus $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are linearly independent and thus a basis of $\text{span}\{(1,1,1),(1,0,1),(0,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if we take the vectors as columns and operate  row reduced form, we will receive to pivot

In pivot matrix the columns which have leading 1, are not directly linear independent, by help of that we choose linear independent vector from main span vectors.